# Does persistence.xml support *.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

If mine persistence.xml file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa">
        <mapping-file>jpaOrm/*.xml</mapping-file>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can spring-data-jpa load all the XML-terminated files in the jpaOrm folder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but I guess you tried and already found out that it doesn't work? The reason is that the mapping files are looked up by using `ClassLoader#getResource()` where the mapping file path is passed in. It does that because the class path is not scannable by default i.e. you can ask for elements on the class path that match a pattern. It can be done of course, but that would hurt performance as class path scanning is one of the most expensive operations.